# How to remove "imageLens is not a function" error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I have installed an extension [Daffodil_Zoom](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-zoom-2.html) 1.0.0.1 (stable) in my magento 1.9.2 site for zooming of product images,

but images are not being zoomed on hover and it is throwing error in browser's console as:

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).imageLens is not a function`

in this line of product images page;

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
              jQuery.noConflict();
              function imgChange(path){
        jQuery(".image_05").attr("src", path);
        jQuery(".undefined").css("background-image",'url('+path+')');
                jQuery(".product-image img:last")   .attr("src", path);
            //jQuery(".product-image img:nth-child(2)").attr("src", path);
}
               var lenswidth = "<?php echo $lensWidth; ?>";
               var lensbordercolor="<?php echo $lensBordercolor; ?>";
                var borderSize="<?php echo $borderSize;?>";
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".image_05").imageLens({
        lensSize: lenswidth,
        borderColor: lensbordercolor,
        borderSize: borderSize
    });
}); 
</script>
```

[image: error in console, mouse pointer on image but not zooming on hover]

Comment: Have you included the library itself? If yes, make sure that you don't have more than one version of jQuery which is not running in `noConflict` mode.

Comment: Okay, see I have updated the question, there is already `noConflict` mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not correct way but it works.try to copy paste the function definition into your same page where you are calling the function, or try to include your js file manually.